# PHP lambda functions and scope

Tags: php, php-5.3, lambda

The below function takes an array and checks to see if its keys and values match the specified datatypes.

I seem to be having some problems with the internal lambda functions that were previously working. I'm running PHP v5.3.6.  They last worked under v5.3.4. They are complaining that the non-passed variable is not in scope.  If I restate that variable as `global` then the error goes away, but the variable is empty.

```
/**
 * @param array $arr, array to be tested
 * @param mixed $keytype
 * @param mixed $valuetype
 * @example acceptable_arr( array(1,2,3,4,'string'), NULL, 'integer') returns false
 * @example acceptable_arr( array('thing'=>1,'other'=>2), 'string', 'integer') returns true
 * @example acceptable_arr( array('thing'=>1,'other'=>2), 'string', 'array') returns false
 */
function acceptable_arr(array $arr,$keytype=NULL,$valuetype=NULL){
     print_r(func_get_args()); //debugging

    $valfail=true; $keyfail=true;
    if($keytype==NULL && $valuetype==NULL) return true;

    if(!is_null($keytype)) {
        $keytest='is_'.$keytype;
        if(function_exists($keytest)){
            $fn_kfail=function($v){return call_user_func($keytest,$v);}; //PROBLEM LINE 218
            $keyfail=(!is_null($keytype)) ? array_sum(array_map($fn_kfail,array_keys($arr))) : false;
        }
    }

    if(!is_null($valuetype)) {
        $valtest='is_'.$valuetype;
        if(function_exists($valtest)){
            $fn_vfail=function($v){return call_user_func($valtest,$v);}; //PROBLEM LINE 226
            $valfail=(!is_null($valuetype)) ? array_sum(array_map($fn_vfail,$arr)) : false;
        }
    }

    return  !($valfail && $keyfail);
}
```

Running the above function outputs this:

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => main
>         )
>
>     [1] => integer
>     [2] => string
> )
> ```
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: keytest in
>   line 218
>
> Warning: call_user_func() expects
>   parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no
>   array or string given in line 218
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: valtest in
>   line 226
>
> Warning: call_user_func() expects
>   parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no
>   array or string given in line 226

Where did the $keytest and $valtest values go? Why are they empty inside the lambda functions even if I declare them global like this?

```
$fn_vfail=function($v){ 
  global $valtest; 
  return call_user_func($valtest,$v);
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`function($v) use ($valtest) { ...`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to this bug: http://bugs.php.net/53958

Which has been fixed in 5.3.6